# How to get count using JPA

Tags: java, jpa

I am writing very simple native query in JPA, it is executing in oracle if I run it directly but failed when run trough JPA.

```
String sql = "select count(*) from demo.sb_test_config cf, isisdba.sb_transpoter st where cf.policy_id = st.policy_id " + 
"and cf.payment_type = 'PAID' and st.sb_t_id = :tId" ;
Query query = em.createNativeQuery(sql);
query.setParameter("tId", 8);
Long response =  (Long)query.getSingleResult();
```

Can some help to find the root cause. What I missing while executing JPA.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide any error logs or message you are receiving.

Comment: post a stack trace, or an exception message at the very least.

Answer (score 0):

How does it fail in JPA?

I can see that you are attempting to use old SQL `join` syntax to get data from two different schemas - is JPA set to allow you to do that?

You did not even say how your attempts fail...

Comment: Its a native query , I think i can also use the old style join syntax as well, not sure

Comment: You can use old style but you should not.

Comment: The main point is that the data is coming from two different schemas - by default JPA connects to one default schema and does not let you query other schemas unless you set aliases

Comment: sorry, Please ignore the schema name, by mistake i changed it at only one place. Otherwise it is same in main query. Error message is  "inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got BINARY"

Comment: Copy and paste the actual SQL statement and the actual error message into the body of your question above.

Comment: Your error message implies that you are selecting binary/boolean value